# Can't strip away attributes and some symbols from elf

Tags: c, gcc, elf, riscv

I am designing a risc-v processor and am using gcc to write some test programs for it.

I see these symbols in the elf file which don't seem to be really needed for the program execution, but I can't seem to be able to strip them away.

Here is my simple program:

```c
// file: loop_c.c
int a = 0;

void _start() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    a += 20;
  }
}
```

I am compiling this into elf as follows:

```sh
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -static -nostdlib -T riscv32i.ld loop_c.c -o loop_c.elf
```

When I look into the hex contents of loop_c.elf, I see the following bits which I can't seem to be able to remove:

[image]

`strip` removes a few of them, but not all. I used the following command:

```sh
riscv32-unknown-elf-strip --strip-unneeded loop_c.elf
```

[image]

Is there any way to remove these bits completely and just set them to 0?

EDIT: Compiler version:

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc (GCC) 11.1.0
```

EDIT2: Is there a name for the parts highlighted in the image above?

EDIT3: Okay, made some progress. The names of the sections that `strip` doesn't remove automatically are (in the second image above):

1. `.shstrtab`
2. `.riscv.attributes`
3. `.sbss`

I could remove the second and third ones with the following command:

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-strip -R .riscv.attributes loop_c.elf
riscv32-unknown-elf-strip -R .sbss loop_c.elf
```

But searching online, it seems that it's very hard or impossible to remove `.shstrtab`. I'm not sure why, but it seems that it's necessary for some reason.

EDIT4: My linker script. This is very bare bones for my CPU design. Obviously nothing close to what is used in the real world:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littleriscv", "elf32-littleriscv", "elf32-littleriscv")
ENTRY(_start)

MEMORY
{
  INST (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 0x1000 /* 4096 bytes or 1024 instructions max, 1 instruction = 4 bytes. */
  DATA (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x2000, LENGTH = 0x1000 /* 4096 bytes or 1024 words of data. 1 word = 4 bytes. */
}

SECTIONS
{
  .text :
  {
    *(.text)
  }> INST

  .data :
  {
    *(.data)
  }> DATA

}
```

Comment: I think we need to know the compiler versions.

Comment: Look, I don't really understand this low level c gcc processor dark magic, but what about the assembly? Is that all okay? And the compilers are basically super human beings, the bits may have a purpose or else they're a bug. And a big "I think" follows.

Comment: @cliff2310 - Edited my post to add compiler version (`11.1.0`)

Comment: @ShambhavGautam - Yes the assembly is fine. The parts highlighted in the first image above are not used by my processor. I'm sure they have some use for the operating system or something else, but for my half-baked, WIP processor design, these extra symbols and characters make it hard for me to automate verification. I would prefer to just purge these bits out and replace them with `0` and I am hoping `gcc` allows us to do that. I don't want to write a utility program for this if I can avoid it.

Comment: @PlastyGrove "I'm sure they have some use for the operating system or something else". Oh, you too don't know what they do. Just goes to show how vast this all is. They might actually be necessary in some conditions. I learnt this fact the hard way a while ago. Most human DNA is called "useless" or something like that but every new year, we find a new purpose for the DNA. It's kinda stupid but I suspect the same thing might happen here in some very specific conditions.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam - Definitely don't know what they are for, but I'm interested in learning :). But they aren't necessary for me at the moment because I don't use them in my CPU. The bits starting from `0x1000` to `0x1051` are the instructions. `0x2000` is where the `.data` section starts. Everything else is unnecessary for me at the moment. Of that I'm certain :).

Comment: Are they debug data? 1. Where is your linker script? 2. Check where this data is coming from. 3. Use `-g0 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections` command line options and see what you get

Comment: @0___________ - Updated my question with the names of the sections that I could find from searching online. Have made some progress, but am coming to the conclusion that removing the `.shstrtab` will render this program unable to run. In fact removing `.sbss` itself makes the program unrunnable in `qemu`. Added my linker script to the question also.

Comment: Did you compile with the command line options I gave you?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get rid of the **.riscv.attribute** section for a simple program that contains a text and a bss section that *MUST* be consecutive and can't tolerate interfering sections. ( The reason is that later I want to save a modified program, this is an interpreter/compiler system).

```
 $(AS) lina.s -o  lina.o -mno-arch-attr

$(LD) -o lina  lina.o   -N
```

As usual *AS* and *LD* points to a riscv gnu assembler and a gnu linker.
For this example the -*N* option snugs the section together and calls for executable code in the bss segment. You may not need this. The program contains an assembler, and the code is placed in the bss section, and is immediately executable without leaving the interpreter.

*objdump -h ciriscv.lina64* result in this:

```
ciriscv.lina64:     file format elf64-littleriscv

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000df48  0000000000010078  0000000000010078  00000078  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, CODE
  1 .bss          001b20b8  000000000001dfc0  000000000001dfc0  0000dfc0  2**0
                  ALLOC
```

[It is infuriating that strip refuses to eliminate this apparently superfluous section. I'd say it has no business refusing even if I want to strip the text section.]